# Monitoring deployed .NET applications

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, deployment, configuration

Given a large number of deployed .NET applications, such as WCF services or ASP.NET front-ends, I would like to create an application that allows me to:

- Check the IIS version on the machine it's running at
- Check the .NET framework version being used
- Check the version of the application deployed
- Check which application pool it's running under

Besides this I would also like to check if the application seems to be running properly and if it has sufficient rights to access a database when deployed.

Right now I'm thinking along the lines of creating a module to be used in each project, which runs a WCF service (self-hosted) that relays all the needed information to a central application.

Anyone have any pointers or ideas on how to accomplish the things I mentioned? Are there easier ways to accomplish basically the same thing? My goal is to display all this information graphically.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have asked several questions in one, better to chop it off. But anyways:

1. To get the IIS version, you can use the `SERVER_SOFTWARE` server variable:

   ```
   Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
   ```

   Check it out more here: [Request.ServerVariables Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525396.aspx)
2. To Check the .NET Version of your application, check the following article: [C# code to determine which versions of the .NET Framework are installed on a system](http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2006/01/30/67654.aspx)
3. To get the application version, you need to look inside the Assembly, like this:

   ```
   Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
   string version = fvi.FileVersion;
   ```
4. To check the application pool, do something like the followings:

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           DirectoryEntries appPools = 
               new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools").Children;

           foreach (DirectoryEntry appPool in appPools)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(appPool.Name);
           }
       }
   ```

You might be interested in checking System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting namespace to visually show them via a graph or something. It is nice to try it.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ambodi has answered the first part of your question, how to check on versions and pools.

The second part of the question "Besides this I would also like to check if the application seems to be running properly and if it has sufficient rights to access a database when deployed." is a little more complicated.

What my company does this: our WCF and other applications that need monitoring are run as DLLs within a common executable (exe) that's hosted and managed as a windows service. So basically, the EXE acts as a shell around the working program. The executable shell, after periodically checking internally on the state of the program it hosts, sends heart-beat timestamp value to a common database table every 10 seconds.

Additionally, we have a controller program that checks the health of the programs by reading the table and finding any program whose hearbeat >10 seconds. This controller has the power to restart these shell programs, too, if they go down for any reason. (Sorry, can't provide you sample code on this stuff. But with that description, you can probably get an idea of what we're doing.)

Comment: yeah, Brian! That is why I mentioned that there are far too many questions bundled as one :)